# How do I allow CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS to be assigned 2 domains

Tags: heroku

Hi I have two origin domains that I want to push my app to.

I went into the Config Vars and set originally
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = domain1.com

but now I need it to be assigned to domain1.com , domain2.org

I tried

= domain1.com , domain2.org

and i tried separating with ; and putting one value by line and also separated with a comma. Did not work.

Comment: I resolved it. It's absolutely stupid. It was not working because i had added a space between the commas.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. It's absolutely stupid. It was not working because i had added a space between the commas